# spf13-vim - Error with neosnippet plugin when editing a file

Tags: filesystem, plugin-spf13

I installed spf13-vim on OS X and when I started do edit a file I get the following errors:

```
Error detected while processing function neosnippet#init#_initialize

Cannot create directory: /Users/.../.cache/neosnippet
```

I suspect that the error is raised because neosnippet plugin does not have permissions to write in the `.cache` directory.

Anybody can help me to fix that?

Comment: Does the user you're logged in as have permissions to write in the `.cache` directory? Does that directory exist? Have you tried creating it?

Answer (score 2):

If It isn't able to read/write to that directory, there are configuration settings to change the cache directory.  According to the [neosnippet documentation](https://github.com/Shougo/neosnippet.vim/blob/master/doc/neosnippet.txt#L233), you can choose the cache directory using the `g:neosnippet#data_directory` variable.  Like so:

```
let g:neosnippet#data_directory = "/path/to/cache/"
```